# Form will not submit when decimal numbers are entered

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cultureinfo, culture, kendo-ui

I have a problem with submitting forms when decimal numbers are present, to be precise if there is a number behind the decimal separator it wont submit. I am working with Asp.NET MVC3, Kendo UI and a different culture, "hr-HR", where the decimal separator is a comma. If I put "en-US" culture (separator is dot) everithing goes smoothly. 
My guess is its a validation problem, but I could be wrong. (Because the form POSTs on US culture)

Also my CurrentUICulture is "en-US" & CurrentCulture is "hr-HR"

Did anyone had a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the form is not posted on server the main reason is client validation. Try to switch it off temporary and try if your form is submitted.

[EnableClientValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.enableclientvalidation%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) method

Comment: I turned it off.
But it is the same

Answer (score 0):

To globalize the client side validation, use jQuery globalization plugin.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by replacing my Kendo NumericTextboxes with HTML 5 input tags. 
Seems HTML 5 is more flexible.